# How to implement a central subscriber model replication?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, data-warehouse

I have a problem please help me.

suppose I have three databases Db1,Db2,DbCenter and tbl_country exists in all of databases.

tbl_country in Db1 has following records:

```
tbl_country

Id    Name
1       US
2       Germany
```

tbl_country in Db2 has following records:

```
tbl_country

Id        Name
1       Australia
2       Italy
```

and the merged records of tbl_country in Db1 and Db2 must be merged in DbCenter,

so tbl_country in DbCenter has following entries:

```
tbl_country

Id    Name
 1      Us
 2      Germany
 3      Australia
 4       Italy
```

the "id" column in all of tables is primary key and identity.

What should I do to the records of two Db1 and Db2 be added in the last of tbl_country of DbCenter.

I'm using transactional replication. set Db1 and Db2 as publishers and specify DbCenter as subscriber and in article properties of Db2 set the action of "Action if name in use" to "Keep existing object unchanged" but it delete the records in DbCenter and substitute them with new ones when the records in "id" column are the same.
Db1 and Db2 are Sql server 2000 version and Db3 is Sql server 2008R2.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain the original key values in the DbCenter database, along with metadata that specifies which database it came from. Then generate a surrogate key that will be used as the PK. That way you both have unique references for each Country records and a way to link back to the source information.

For example:-

```
ID_SK SOURCE_ID SOURCE_DB NAME
1     1         Db1       US
2     2         Db1       Germany
3     1         Db2       Australia
4     2         Db2       Italy
```

Answer (score 0):

If Db1 and Db2 have overlapping primary key values, I don't think there is any way to do this. If you have control over the schema, and are able to change it, you might want to change the primary keys to the uniqueidentifier type (instead of int) which is guaranteed to be globally unique.